# How can I structure my database to order by a function dependent on time efficiently in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, database-design, ranking

I have a table with ID's and KPI's like this

```
+----+---------------------+------------+--------+
| id | created_at          | page_views | shares |
+----+---------------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2015-02-25 07:24:50 |         10 |      3 |
|  2 | 2015-04-22 13:48:46 |         40 |      1 |
|  3 | 2014-09-17 15:26:51 |         28 |      5 |
|  4 | 2014-08-09 16:27:48 |        149 |      2 |
|  5 | 2015-01-21 15:56:30 |          3 |      1 |
+----+---------------------+------------+--------+
```

I want to make a ranking algorithm along the lines of

```
SELECT id FROM pages ORDER BY (pages.page_views + pages.shares * 40) / (NOW() - created_at);
```

But I feel like this isn't scalable with increasing number of KPIs and entrees.
Is there a way to structure my table to efficiently rank using KPIs with decreasing score as time goes on?

Comment: How about precomputing the order criteria every x seconds?

Comment: I cache the results but I am still afraid it might take too long. Is using "order by" like this okay?

Comment: `(NOW() - created_at)` is not how you do date subtraction.  Look at the DATE functions in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a `pageranking` column and update it regularly (daily?) using a batch job.

This will provide good search performance at the cost of using slightly out-of-date page rankings.

Comment: Read more carefully. The function's value depends on the current time, so simply precomputing the result won't work. The order of two rows can change in time without them being modified.

Comment: Thanks Vatev! I've modified (=completely rewritten) my answer.